# Displaying array content

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have an array as below;

```
<?php  

foreach ($arr['sections'] as $key => $value) 
{
   return  $key;
}

?>
```

Which returns the values part1, part2, part3 which I want to put into the following

```
get_template_part( 'content', '$key');
```

So that I get a block of code to display the 3 lines with the part in place but i can't figure out the correct way of getting it to output, I have tried something like

```
<?php  

foreach ($arr['sections'] as $key => $value) 
{
   $output  = "get_template_part( 'content', '";
   $output .= $key;
   $output .= "');";

   return $output;

}

?>
```

But it's not working, any advice or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call the function for each key by passing parameter

```
foreach ($arr['sections'] as $key => $value) 
{

get_template_part( 'content',$key);

}
```

or if you want all the content in some variable

```
$output='';
foreach ($arr['sections'] as $key => $value) 
{

$output.=get_template_part( 'content',$key);

}
echo $output; /* will have the content from all parts (part1, part2, part3) */
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the array so we don't know what you want to pass exactly, but how about:

```
$output = call_user_func_array('get_template_part', $arr['sections']);
```

Or if for whatever reason you actually want the "keys" passed:

```
$output = call_user_func_array('get_template_part', array_keys($arr['sections']));
```

Or to add the 'content':

```
array_unshift($arr['sections'], 'content');
$output = call_user_func_array('get_template_part', $arr['sections']);
```

Comment: My bad, if that's what they wanted then I should have downvoted them.  Didn't see it as how to iterately call a function given their code. If you edit your post I'll upvote you.

Comment: Guess I need to get used to the poster not having a rudimentary knowledge even when it seems like they should from their question.

Comment: Some times its a bit hard to understand what they need but sometimes your guess works for them

Comment: But I do explain the array and the output that it gives, what did I miss?

Comment: 1. no you didn't show the array, use `print_r()` or preferably `var_export()` 2. You stated, "I have tried something like", "but it's not working".  You have an accepted answer so roll with it :-)